# When I click on Visual editor in wordpress It does not work

Tags: wordpress

When I click on Visual editor in wordpress, it does not work. It is locked. I am not able to click on visual and text. I want to add blog post but I can't access visual or text editor in the post page.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined
    at Function.b.closeAllTags (quicktags.min.js:1)
    at d (load-scripts.php:782)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php:782)
    at i (wp-tinymce.php:3)
    at HTMLDocument.m (wp-tinymce.php:3)
```

Comment: Your theme or one of the plugins might be causing compatibility issues. Try disabling them one at a time until you identify which one is causing the issue.

Comment: I had an issue where I had a Chrome or browser extension interfering with Wordpress editor. Try disabling your browser extensions.

Comment: This seems more like a question on how to use Wordpress, and not a programming question. If it is a programming question, then it needs the relevant code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling all your plugins and see if you can switch between editor modes.  If you can then there's a plugin issue so try switching each one back on individually until you find the issue.  The other solution would be to upgrade WordPress to the latest version on your test system first to ensure you don't break your current production system to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I have deactivated all the plugins and try but still it is not working

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Update WordPress to the latest version if you have not already done so.

Comment: I am using wordpress version 4.4.8

Comment: I have updated my wordpress version and it is working.Thank you